# Eclipse Remote Debugging CDT tutorial

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, remote-debugging

TL;DR: is there a step by step tutorial to do remote code debugging using Eclipse Neon?

I have the source code in a Linux machine with a GCC dev environment. Normally, I ssh to the box, edit the file, and compile/debug using gdb, and it works, but it is a bit clunky for me.

I am now trying to debug the code from my Windows machine using the latest Eclipse version (Neon as of this writing).

I've tried following the instructions online ([like this one](http://www.2net.co.uk/tutorial/eclipse-rse)), but they all seem to point towards (cross-)compiling the code locally, deploying it remotely and debugging there. This is not what I'm after. I essentially want to use Eclipse as a remote text editor+gdb interface, with the building and compiling being done in the remote system.

I've installed CDT, plus pretty much any plugin remotely related to remote development

- Remote System Explorer
- Remote Launch
- GCC Cross compiler support
- Remote (over TCF/TE) Run/Debug Launcher
- Direct Remote C++ Debugging
- TCF C/C++ Debugger
- TM Terminal

So far, I can connect to the remote system, create a Remote Project and edit the source code.
I don't need Eclipse to compile the code (I can do that separately) but I'm unable to debug the code.

- Using C/C++ Remote Application fails in many creative ways when trying to find gdb in the remote system.

  - Using GDB (DSF) Automatic Remote Debugging Launcher ends in a **java.lang.NullPointerException**, which also invalidates the configuration
  - Using Direct Remote Debugging Launcher asks about a remote workspace, then complains with "**Error with command: gdb --version Cannot run program "gdb": Launching failed**"
- Remote Application complains about the Process/Image field. Setting it to the binary output doesn't enable the Debug button, so no dice.
- TCF is dead in the water. It doesn't recognize the SSH connections I set up on RSE, it asks for the username password (I use public keys) and root password (?!) Even when entering that info, it fails to continue.

On a whim, I tried NetBeans, and followed the instructions [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/remote-modes.html#glxhr), and got it working in five minutes. The mode I'm following is the "Full Remote Development" according to NetBeans. The reason I'll still need to stick to Eclipse is that it is the dev environment that we use in the company, and it makes little sense to me to add another IDE to do something that Eclipse by all rights should do no problem.

What I find is that the walkthroughs for Eclipse I've found are either

1. Using plugins that are now either deprecated, not supported or [have been completely reworked](http://www.2net.co.uk/tutorial/eclipse-rse). Eclipse crashes and burns on these.
2. [Trying to compile locally and deploy remotely](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Al6OZ2kF_qA), doing things like embedded even, but that's not what I'm looking for.
3. Using the Eclipse DStore client-server combo, which is essentially an alternative to SSH, but not what I'm looking for either.

I'm then hoping someone has written/found a tutorial that is relatively simple to follow (it is, after all, a relatively simple thing to do, as NetBeans has proven), and that works on any version of Eclipse.

I'll consider using an older version of Eclipse, but if so, please be specific in which version I should use, and which plugins I should install.

Comment: I am almost sure this question is be flagged by the administrator as off-topic (and receive some downvotes from others). I think you are better off just ask this question in the chat.

Comment: There are a few similar questions in the site, although I have to admit mine is wordier than most of them. I just wanted to show that I did my homework before asking. Still, other people can benefit from the answer, so I believe it's relevant.

Comment: I understand the question is relevant.... but the rule here is that questions cannot revolve any subjective judgement.... which basically rule out any recommendation for external resources. By the way, I am totally OK with this question, but the administrator might disagree........